# List of geocode of address in google map

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a small application using the **Google Maps API**.

It will display every fastfood location in an area. I know there are already some applications that do the same thing, but *I would like to learn and do my own stuff* :).

E.g. I have a list of 1000 address, and I would like for *every of them* to be displayed on the map. S

- Should my application send requests 1000 times to Google the longitude and latitude of the location for each time a user would want to use my application?
- Or should I store the longitude and the latitude on my database? If so, *is there a way to obtain them through a request?* I know there is a way to obtain it one by one, not to have all of them.

Comment: beware of the google's api restriction: you can make only 2500 calls or so per day. it would better to obtain them once, and store them in db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Geocoder API has a request limit per API key (you have to obtain one of those): 2500 calls or so per day. I would suggest you use the Geocoder to obtain the Lat and Lon of all your adresses and save them to SQLite, so you can reuse the locations all the time. 
Just write a loop that goes through all your adresses, makes the request to google and stores the lat/lon information. If you hit their limit, you can continue the next day.